# I have query in my code for search button

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 6 input fields in my search. I want to search data if user selects one or more input fields. 
e.g. 1) If i select only city then result should be of that city.
2) If i select city, area, Property type then result should be properties of that city according to the area and property type.

This is what I have tried:

```
$strquery="SELECT * FROM sell_rent_prop_detl WHERE city like '%" .  
           $_POST['city'] . "%' and area <= '" . $_POST['area'] . "'   
           and prop_type= '" . $_POST['ptype'] . "'   
           and bedroom= '" . $_POST['bedroom'] ."'";    

$results=mysql_query($strquery);
```

Comment: Sounds great! I think you forgot to paste your attempt though...plus what the actual question is.

Comment: I have an answer for you, just post what you've tried, and then i will post the answer for you.

Comment: I have 6 input fields these are: City, Area, Property Type, min Price, Max Price and bedroom. 1) If i select any one field from them then it show the result according to it. 2) If i select all fields or 2 or 3 fields the result should be according to all that input fields.

Comment: that is just a description, please post your code/query

Comment: $strquery="SELECT * FROM `sell_rent_prop_detl` WHERE city like '%" . $_POST['city'] . "%' and area <= '" . $_POST['area'] . "'  and prop_type= '" . $_POST['ptype'] . "' and bedroom= '" . $_POST['bedroom'] . "'";
$results=mysql_query($strquery);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with your php like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE 1=1";  

if($_POST['city'])
   $query .= " AND `City` LIKE  %'".$_POST['city']."'%";
if($_POST['area'])
   $query .= " AND `Area` =  %'".$_POST['area']."'%";  
if($_POST['ptype'])
   $query .= " AND `prop_type` =  %'".$_POST['ptype']."'%";
if($_POST['bedroom'])
   $query .= " AND `bedroom` =  %'".$_POST['bedroom']."'%";

if($_POST['city'] || $_POST['area'] || $_POST['ptype'] || $_POST['bedroom'])
     $results=mysql_query($query);
else 
    echo "nothing is selected";
```

Comment: I tried your code it works fine for all fields selection. But i also want result after only one field selected or two or three fields selected.

Comment: I added "!='Select'" and it works for me

Comment: Thanks  Luthando Loot

Comment: @Rupali nice, i am glad my answer helped

Answer (score 0):

You can try multiple select

[Multiple Select HTML Form Fields PHP Parse Tutorial](https://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/Multiple-Select-HTML-Form-Fields-PHP-Parse-Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

$query = "SELECT * FROM `sell_rent_prop_detl` WHERE ";
if($_POST['city']!='Select')
   $query .= " AND `cityp` =  '".$_POST['city']."'";
if($_POST['area']!='Select')
   $query .= " AND `area` <=  '".$_POST['area']."'";
if($_POST['ptype']!='Select')
   $query .= " AND `prop_type` =  '".$_POST['ptype']."'";
if($_POST['bedroom']!='Select')
   $query .= " AND `bedroom` =  '".$_POST['bedroom']."'";
if($_POST['city'] || $_POST['area'] || $_POST['ptype'] || $_POST['bedroom'])
     $results=mysql_query($query);
else 
 echo "nothing is selected";